# First Android app not running

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following the steps as in [android training google](http://developer.android.com/training/) and my `activity_main.xml` is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have defined the hint strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">mainActivity</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

[image: AVD details]

But when I click on run button, it shows no activity !

Comment: And what's the question?...

Comment: Sorry. See my updated question

Comment: Code please, else cannot help

Comment: @Nitish please put manifest and java file,what's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put this code in **AndroidManifest** file..

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivityname"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
 </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `MainActivity.java` have you inserted the code?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an Android application from a .xml file, you must run from a .java file. Choose **Run As > Android Application.** Also ensure you have an emulator set up and ready or a real device to run on connected and ready.